# Asus A52JC won't start after BIOS upgrade

Tags: laptop, installation, bios

I have an Asus A52JC laptop.

I downloaded the BIOS from Asus' website, went into BIOS Flash Utility and ran the BIOS flash update. After that, the computer should have restarted, but now I can't start it anymore, as if it's dead.

Is there a way to install the BIOS again, for example from a USB stick?